# as I can create a navigation in WPF with active functions or page view

Tags: c#, c++, vb.net, xaml

I have a problem, I'm programming in vb.net wpf in which the use navigationservices.navigate () function and move to another page is not loading the functions of this new product. generating a problem in passing data and activate functions.

I need your help to finish. since this is a problem that no one can sorting. and I'm starting in this WPF

Comment: Welcome to SO :-) I think to help we might need to see your code, please edit the question to show it.

Comment: ok tanks stefan. my code i add. to the next coment

Comment: If MsgBox("Advertencia, no se instalara el equipo a menos que todas las Configuraciones de la Orden de compra esten finalizadas", MsgBoxStyle.Information) = MsgBoxResult.Ok Then
                Dim install As New V_instalacion

Comment: NavigationService.Navigate(install)
                NavigationService.RemoveBackEntry()
                install.vista2.Visibility = Visibility.Visible
                install.vista1.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden
                Dim selecto As String = Grid_ordenes_compra.SelectedItem(0).ToString
                id_delcambio = selecto.ToString
                Stipo = selecto.ToString
                Try

Comment: it is better to show the code **in the question** that is what "edit" is for. Much better, you can format it as code there too.

Comment: how to show my code in this place! ok. my code is.

Comment: https://codepaste.net/trv7s9 in this place obtain the code

Answer (score 0):

this is not a answer only is a attachtment

If MsgBox("Advertencia, no se instalara el equipo a menos que todas las Configuraciones de la Orden de compra esten finalizadas", MsgBoxStyle.Information) = MsgBoxResult.Ok Then
                Dim install As New V_instalacion
                NavigationService.Navigate(install)
                NavigationService.RemoveBackEntry()
                install.vista2.Visibility = Visibility.Visible
                install.vista1.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden
                Dim selecto As String = Grid_ordenes_compra.SelectedItem(0).ToString
                id_delcambio = selecto.ToString
                Stipo = selecto.ToString
                Try

and i only call a view install. but in view install called my function have a error

Comment: Please edit your question to contain this information. This "answer" will be deleted exactly for the one reason that it is not an answer.